# Why doesn't ASCII art look good in textfields like in console/terminal outputs?

Tags: javafx, console, ascii, textfield

As a fun side project I decided to make an ASCII art generator in JavaFX. Everything turn out to be good but I have encountered a problem. I want to print the converted art on a textfield so that the user can copy it and place it in the youtube comment section or whatever. However, the art doesn't show as nicely on the textfield as when I print it in the console.

Here you could see the desired output in the console with System.out.println:
[image]

However this ishow it looks in the textfield:

[image]

Here it is again when pasted:

```
  _            _   _ ____  _____ 
 | |_ ___  ___| |_/ |___ \|___ / 
 | __/ _ \/ __| __| | __) | |_ \ 
 | ||  __/\__ \ |_| |/ __/ ___) |
  \__\___||___/\__|_|_____|____/
```

When searching on the internet for other ASCII generators, they seem to have the same problem, it looks good but when you copy and paste it somewhere it just gets smushed and is unreadable.

Comment: Likely setting the [font family](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typefont) to `monospace` or specifying a specific monospace font like `Courier` will fix your problem.  It can be set via css (as linked previously) or via [an api call in code](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Font.html#font(java.lang.String))

Comment: Eventually I have figured that out, however when I copy the monospaced font and try to paste it in say, a youtube comment, the style doesn't seem to get copied with it. Is there a way in javaFX where you can copy the whole text with its style aswell?

Comment: Ask a new question about copying text with style.  It is a different thing with a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the console uses a monospace font. All characters use the same amount of space regardless of how narrow the character is (e.g. `|` and `w`). If you want your text to work in variable-width fonts, you will likely have to change your code to suit each font